# Почему прописывается слэш в начале ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ссылка передаёт содержимое атрибута в плеер

```
<a href="#" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com">
```

А в плеере уже выводится так

```
$('.jp-image').html('<a href="'+$(this).data('url')+'">' +
  '<img src="'+$(this).data('image')+'" alt=""></a>');
```

И получается ссылка с лишним слэшем вначале адреса

```
<a href="/http://stackoverflow.com">
```

Как убрать этот слэш?
Получается адрес неправильный

```
http://stackoverflow.com/http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Больше информации, это просто куски кода которые ни о чем не говорят, что из себя представляет элемент с классом jp-image? Где он вообще делся? :)

Comment: Больше ничего нет. В этот div вставляется скриптом ссылка`<div class="jp-image"></div>`

Comment: Как запускается приведенный Вами в пример jQuery код? Какие происходят действия чтобы его запустить, мало того Вы и тег <a> не закрыли, это просто вырванные куски из кода по которым ничего сказать не возможно.

Comment: мало того эту куски кода еще и с кучей ошибок.

Comment: При чём тут не закрытый тег, это просто пример. Если я дам весь код, тогда точно ничего не понятно будет.

Comment: Где ошибки в коде?

Comment: Это не пример, куски кода, мало того которые между собой не стыкуются ни как. Напишите нормальный пример, где явно видно все блоки что они содержат и что вы нажимаете при этом что выходит именно такое, у Вас судя по все элементарная опечатка в коде, перечитайте свой код.

Comment: $(this).data('url') так использовать очень плохо да и нельзя, правильно писать так, если Вы хотите прочитать атрибут, то писать нужно так $(this).attr('data-url') https://api.jquery.com/data/ Читайте тут как правильно использовать $.data()

Comment: так же, да и лучше, и читабельней использовать создание элементов методами jQuery $('<a/>', {href: 'http://mysite.com'});

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35532/discussion-between-shnur-and--).

Comment: Удалите комментарии

Comment: Сергей, возможно, на вашей HTML-странице есть элемент [`BASE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base), в атрибуте `href` которого прописано `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть тег <base href="/" /> когда он используется - у ссылок с относительным путём подставляется значение из этого тега. https://jsfiddle.net/8cxwnvpz/

```
<base href="http://artlebedev.ru"/>
<a href="kovodstvo">Руководство</a>
```

или вот https://jsfiddle.net/w25kafuf/

```
<base href="/"/>
<a href="user/login/" target="_blank">Log in</a>
```

Comment: У меня нет base ссылок. Но сейчас попробую наоборот поставить, чтоб адрес сайта подставлялся,

Comment: Не понял, у меня же есть только полный путь, тогда не получится

Comment: Думал так получится, но мне ни как не сделать относительный путь        `<base href="http://artlebedev.ru"/>
<a href="kovodstvo">Руководство</a>`

Comment: Хотя можно с пустым попробовать `<base href="">` Но только если даже и получится, вариант какой-то ни ахх.